# Show more options in both top and bottom action bars android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to add few menu Items on my action Bar.

I have 5 buttons and 1 Button for searchView.

If I just put 5 Menu Items , it shows only 4 at the top and blocks away the Text of Action bar.

So I used  `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`

It causes the Actionbar to show on Below as well as Top. But on Bottom action bar, All i can see is 4 Buttons. There is no sign of 5th Button. How can I place 5th Button and an extra search Button on Top bar. Since there is no Menu buttons on top bar now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a image friend?

I am guessing that you have to many MenuItems and they are just pushing the 5th away to the right because of the limited space on the action bar. It depends a little bit on what kind of ActionBar you are using, in what target and what version of Android.

Have you considered using a ActionOverflow button for listing the other options?

Comment: Yes the fifth is going outside of screen, but my question is, How can I put the two that are going outside on Top action bar, No idea about ActionOverflow